# Sticky form undefined offset

Tags: php

I have a 5x2 HTML table: http://jsfiddle.net/duxTU/

- The table is enclosed in a form.
- When the form is submitted it redirects to same page
- The input field values are stored in an associative array
- The values are displayed in respective fields where they were initially entered.

Code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $contacts_array  array(
        $_POST["name1"] => $_POST['name2'],
        $_POST["name3"] => $_POST['name4'],
        $_POST["name5"] => $_POST['name6'],
        $_POST["name7"] => $_POST['name8'],
        $_POST["name9"] => $_POST['name10']);

$array_filtered=array_filter($contacts_array);  
$arrayKeys = array_keys($array_filtered);
$arrayValues = array_values($array_filtered);
}
?>
```

The array has been filtered to omit null values that may creep in.

Now, how do I make the the HTML form display values? I know about sticky forms but since i must keep the form size constant(5x2), I am trying to use code similar to following

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $arrayKeys[0]; ?> ">  
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $arrayValues[0]; ?> ">
```

... till $arrayKeys[4] and $arrayValues[4], respectively.

This gives me undefined offsets, for example `$arrayKeys[5]` was not set as no value was entered in the respective form column before submission.

Any solution to this issue??

Comment: if the array if 5x2 then you should be going up to 4 not 5... 0,1,2,3,4 = 5 values

Comment: ya thanks for pointing out but that would not solve the original problem.

Comment: why are you filtering out the nulls again? It seems that if you stopped doing that your problems would go away..

Comment: if i don't filter the nulls,the array generated from the form contain nulls

Comment: all of you work is based on positional values of everything... if you filter out values you have no hope of know where the blanks are when you go to restore the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display values, a `foreach` would work great:

```
foreach ($array_filtered as $k=>$v) {
   echo "<input type='text' value='".$k."'>";
   echo "<input type='text' value='".$v."'>";
}
```

`foreach` loops through an array. `$k` is the current key. `$v` is the current value.

Of course, this should be inside of your form HTML.

Comment: very sorry..there was a typo..

$array_filtered=array_filter($contacts_array);

I have edited the main question..

Comment: Ouch.  Paragraphs deleted. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you:

```
<?php
    function getPost($param){
        return isset($_POST[$param])?$_POST[$param]:"";
    }
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Age</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name1" value="<?= getPost("name1") ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name2" value="<?= getPost("name2") ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name3" value="<?= getPost("name3") ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name4" value="<?= getPost("name4") ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name5" value="<?= getPost("name5") ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name6" value="<?= getPost("name6") ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name7" value="<?= getPost("name7") ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name8" value="<?= getPost("name8") ?>"></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name9" value="<?= getPost("name9") ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="name10" value="<?= getPost("name10") ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The getPost helper was created because I didn't want to have to type the conditional every time.

You can filter out the nulls for whatever other form processing you are doing.